# Inserting data into mysql using jquery yes or no vote

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui

How can i update the database by adding users choices? I have two fields in the database for this purpose, when the user click on yes, it updates the (useful) field and (not_useful) if clicked on no button. I am very new on javascript, so please be patient! :) I appreciate any help in advance.

PHP

```
<?php
  require 'db/conn.php':
  $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

  if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table_user WHERE table_user_id = $id")){
    if($result->num_rows){
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "
         <div class='rating'>
           <center>
             <p>Are you alrite " . $row['table_user_name'] . "?</p>
             <div>
               <button type='button' id='yes'>Yes</button>
               <button type='button' id='no'>No</button>
             </div>
           </center>
        </div>
        <div class='1' style='display:none;'>Text YES</div>
        <div class='2' style='display:none;'>Text NO</div>
        ";
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#yes").click(function(){
    $(".rating").hide();
    $(".1").show();
  });
  $("#no").click(function(){
    $(".rating").hide();
    $(".2").show();
  });
});
```

Comment: AJAX can solve your problem

Comment: He may not need ajax if he's just going to submit the form.  Ajax would probably just confuse even more.

Comment: I just want to store in database the user choice and every time some user click on yes or no, it updates the database increasing the field value without refreshing the page. Only the specific class with the form.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET column = column +1` - with optional `WHERE column_x = 'something'`

Comment: The problem is how do I add the option clicked in the database increasing the value already there

Comment: I found this http://www.9lessons.info/2009/08/vote-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html after Googling "vote yes no javascript mysql php" - you'll need to further your research from there. There were many results found using those keywords.

Comment: I think something goes in JS function to update the database

Comment: @Fred-ii- believe me i did a lot of searching before come here and post my problem. This article that you have sent, i already saw and did not help me cause it is to advanced for my case. I do not need something like that. Just need to update my database with the user choice. But thank you anyway for your attempt to help

Comment: You're welcome. JS is not my strong points. I know how to do it in pure PHP/SQL, but not JS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62086/discussion-between-andre-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some working hard, i found a solution. Sharing for those who is facing similar problem. This was my solution. Anyways, have fun! ;)

***I think there's a better way to organize the JS script to interact with the php files which manage the sql scripts. If someone would like to help optimize it, will be welcome.***

PHP main

```
<?php
  require 'db/conn.php':
  $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

  if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id = $id")){
    if($result->num_rows){
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "
         <div class='rating'>
           <center>
             <p>Are you alrite " . $row['user_name'] . "?</p>
             <div id='rating-div'>
               <a href='#' id='yes' class='custom-btn'>Yes</a>
               <a href='#' id='no' class='custom-btn'>No</a>
               <input type='hidden' id='" . $id . "' />
             </div>
           </center>
        </div>
        ";
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('#yes').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var usr_id = $('#rating-div input').attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'db/rating-yes.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {'action': 'rating', 'usr_id': user_id},
            success: function(data, status){
                if(data == "ok"){
                    $('.rating').html('<p>Nice!</p>');
                }//end of if
            },//end of success function
            error: function(xhr, desc, err){
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError: "+ err);
            }
        });//end of ajax
    }); //end of onclick function
}); //end of main function

$(function(){
    $('#no').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var usr_id = $('#rating-div input').attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'db/rating-no.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {'action': 'rating', 'usr_id': user_id},
            success: function(data, status){
                if(data == "ok"){
                    $('.rating').html('<p>Oh no! :(</p>');
                }//end of if
            },//end of success function
            error: function(xhr, desc, err){
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError: "+ err);
            }
        });//end of ajax
    }); //end of onclick function
}); //end of main function
```

PHP rating-yes

```
<?php

 $rating = $_POST['action'];
 $user_id = $_POST['usr_id'];

 if($rating == "rating") {

  $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
  $db = mysql_select_db('your_database');

  if(mysql_query("UPDATE table SET useful = useful + 1 WHERE user_id = $user_id")){
    echo "ok";
  }
 }

?>
```

PHP rating-no

```
<?php

 $rating = $_POST['action'];
 $user_id = $_POST['usr_id'];

 if($rating == "rating") {

 $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
 $db = mysql_select_db('your_database');

 if(mysql_query("UPDATE table SET not_useful = not_useful + 1 WHERE user_id = $user_id")){
echo "ok";
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect your mySQL database directly with JavaScript from client browser. Event if it would be possible you really don't want to do that because you would have to include mysql login credentials into your JavaScript which is served to client computers.

Of course you could use database like LocalStorage from within JavaScript but these databases are on client computer. If I got it right thats not what you are looking.

You have to send the data to a script on your server which then insert them into your mySQL database. As you stated you don't like the browser to reload to just submitting a form is not an option. In these cases AJAX is used. You will find several tutorials how to send data with JavaScript / JQuery using AJAX to your server.

On server side you could handle for example with a php script. The code you have posted to your question is not PHP but simple HTML. Fred -ii- posted some sample SQL statements to increment a column. I would recommend you to use [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php) with [mysql driver](http://php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-mysql.php) as this helps you to prevent security issues.

Comment: I only insert in the post the part of the code that i thought need to be modified for my propose. I use php on this page to manipulate data, i will edit the code inserting the php part to help understanding my case

Comment: You have to send the data from browser to server. Have a look therefore on AJAX. For example you could start with these tutorial: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php

Comment: Thank you @jelhan. The tutotial helped a lot to solve my problem.